# How to locate a checkbox and know it's checked status present in a table cell

Tags: selenium, xpath

I need to locate (done partially) and find out it's checked status of a checkbox placed in a table row and in a table cell. Here is the html code I could pull and the locator I used. Problem I am facing is that, inside the Html code, I don't see the html for the checkbox, just empty, even though in the web page, the checkbox appears and it's state is alterable from checked to unchecked and vice versa.

**xpath Locator:** `//table[@class='x-grid3-row-table']//tr[@role='presentation']//td[@role='gridcell'][10]/div/div`

**Html Code(partial, just up to the TD cell):**

```
<td id="x-auto-380" role="gridcell" class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-idRev " style="width:51px;" xpath="1">
    <div unselectable="on" class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-idRev"> 
        <div class="x-grid3-check-col x-grid3-cc-idRev">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Please share the url. Maybe some javascript or css is going on. Your XPath uses the tenth td([10]) , that is correct?

Comment: checked checkbox element normally contains `selected` class name

Comment: Yes @SiebeJongebloed You are correct, it is at 10th cell of the Row.
BTW, I may not be able to provide the URL, because our Client may not approve of that.
I can provide some more HTML, if it helps

Comment: if the checkbox is checked, unselectable attribute is set to off?

Comment: No. What is happening in my code is that when checkbox is 'ON', the last <div> class will be 'class="x-grid3-check-col **x-grid3-check-col-on** x-grid3-cc-idRev", other wise just '<div class="x-grid3-check-col x-grid3-cc-idRev"
Based on that class attribute, I could able to check the status.

Thanks @Prophet for your suggestion, which led me to this.

Comment: I think you want to check the parent "<table>" tag for "-selected" in class attribute.  (In ExtJS each row is it's own table...)